# Sending a JavaScript array to PHP via POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, post

I am trying to send a JavaScript array to a PHP file via POST.

**JS:**

```
var songlist = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3'];

var sendData = function(){
    var data = songList.join(',')
    $.post('test.php', {data: data}).always(function() {
        window.location = 'test.php';
    });
}
sendData();
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php
$songData = $_POST['data'];
$songData = explode(',', $songData); 
print_r(array_values($songData));
?>
```

when sendData(); directs me to test.php I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: data

Why doesn't the data variable have any value when I try to print or use it?

Comment: I am not sure, but try use $_POST->data. Maybe this is object, becouse you send it to your script like object, no array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) $.post('url')** - Ajax request is done by `$.post()` method and you have given `"testing.php"` as url which is invalid.

**2) window.location = 'test.php'** - This is used for redirecting to specific page and you have redirected  to `'test.php'` without any parameter/data. Thats why its showing **"Notice: Undefined index: data"**

**3) Try to understand how ajax works. Follow it -**

```
var songlist = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3'];

var sendData = function() {
  $.post('test.php', {
    data: songlist
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
sendData();
// test.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $songData = $_POST['data'];
    print_r($songData);
}}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, the response in console is working, but how do I see if it printed to test.php without the page redirecting me to it?

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to print the value to test.php , then you dont need to use ajax. Just redirect with -  var data = songList.join(','); window.location = "test.php?data="+data;  And use explode() function on your php script to get back array from string.

Answer (score 8):

That's not how POST request works. Read more about Ajax, but for now, that's how you should do it.

```js
var songlist = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3'];

var sendData = function() {
  $.post('test.php', {
    data: songlist
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
sendData();
```

```html
// test.php
<?php
$songData = $_POST['data'];
print_r($songData);
?>
```

Comment: this solution is what i was think about there is no need to convert array to string