# Javascript How to hide a function from my web app (by using php?)

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

I am making a web app that has typical javascript structure below.
I must hide at least a function or some formulas from the public code because someone can save the page on his computer without paying for the web app membership. I am not sure how to do that.

"edit" I found the answer and is in the following snippet. My problem now is how to pass the data outside the $.post( )?

```js
   function analysis(){
          var  L = "sting";
          var  w   = JSON.stringify(w);
          var  counter = "sting";
  $.post('../php/solver2.php',{L : L , w : w , counter:counter },
 function(data){  jdata  = JSON.parse(data); });
     
            var jdata  = JSON.parse(tempJdata);
            var x          = jdata.x;
            var v          = jdata.v;
       
       return [x v];
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: read about ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer sending multiple arrays to php process them and return processed arrays.

```js
          var  L = "sting";
          var  w   = JSON.stringify(w);
          var  counter = "sting";
  $.post('../php/solver2.php',{L : L , w : w , counter:counter },
 function(data){  var jdata  = JSON.parse(data);
                  var x          = jdata.x;
                  var v          = jdata.v;});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON.stringify() on your array and use AJAX to send it to your php script.

On php side, you can json_decode() that same array and work with it.

You could protect that PHP script with sessions, and return an error if one is not allowed to access it.

Comment: So the 1. JSON.stringify() will send a string that codifies the array with post to php file 2. ajax to do what exactly ? 3. decode the string in to array process it in php and output the results in to html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop someone to download your client side script code.

Check this [How do I hide javascript code in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869312/how-do-i-hide-javascript-code-in-a-webpage)

And i can check every client side code with the browser developer tools.

**Edit:**
You mean this:

[How do I pass JavaScript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

[Sending a JavaScript array to PHP via POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570103/sending-a-javascript-array-to-php-via-post/43570164)

[Pass Javascript Array -> PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035547/pass-javascript-array-php)

This are your HTTP request methods(check for browser compatibility):

[HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Every operation on the server-side is hidden(on a normal way without bugs or something else) and the result you send to the client is public.